# What's the effect of increasing the Earth's rotation on climate?

Tags: climate, earth-like, day-night

The Earth's rotation speeds up slowly but without limit.

How does this affect the climate?

I am thinking that day and night temperatures would even out so that there would be less wind, but I don't know if we can quantify that, the consequences, or what other effects might take place.

Comment: The limit of *"without limit"* is one rotation every 1.4 hours, where the centrifugal acceleration at the Equator equals the gravitational acceleration and stuff starts wandering off into space as there is nothing keeping it down.

Answer (score 2):

If the speed increases slowly, the [Coriolis effect](https://education.nationalgeographic.org/resource/coriolis-effect/) will become pronounced and I think that will result in stronger storms and hurricanes.

A more severe effect I can think of is that without any limit on the increase of the speed, eventually, the Earth will disintegrate. It'll become like a pancake in the equator and eventually things will start to fly off.

**Edit:** As mentioned in the comments, the limit is one rotation every 1.4 hours. Additionally, the [Milankovitch cycles](https://climate.nasa.gov/news/2948/milankovitch-orbital-cycles-and-their-role-in-earths-climate/#:%7E:text=The%20Milankovitch%20cycles%20include%3A,is%20pointed%2C%20known%20as%20precession.) will also be affected and hence the climate!

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a moon, its effect will lower the maximum rotational speed that the Earth can sustain without disintegrating. The Earth would experience greater high tides in some area and less high tides in other areas due to the oceans moving toward the equator, and would experience less tidal variation due to the moon having less time to draw the tide. The plate tectonics would become less violent in the directions that they now move due to less time for the moon's interaction, and become more violent due to centripetal spin forces upon them moving them toward the equator. The winds would become less due to less time for the sun and moon to act upon any particular Earth surface location. The winds would become more near to the equator due to the expansion of the Earth near to the equator and subsequently closer to the moon and its interaction with them.